# How to transform this memcpy into a for?

Tags: c++, memcpy

What is the difference between these two?

---

```
for (int i = 0; i < numSamples; i++) {
    mData[sampleIndex++] = *buffer++ * (1.0f / 32768);
}
```

and

```
memcpy(&mData[sampleIndex], buffer, (numSamples * sizeof(float)));
```

---

If I understood correct, the first copies `numSamples` `float` values to `mData`, one by one. The second one, copies `numSamples*sizeof(float)` bytes to `mData`. Since we're copying `numSaples` * `number of bytes on float`, I think they do the same thing, but the first one actually multiplies things before passing to `mData`.

So, is there a way to transform the `memcpy` into a `for`? Something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numSamples * sizeof(float); i++) {
    //What to put here?
}
```

Context:

```
const int32_t   mChannelCount;
const int32_t   mMaxFrames;
int32_t sampleIndex;
float          *mData;
float *buffer;
```

Comment: I don't understand what the goal it

Comment: The loop does multiplication and copy. `memcpy` only does copy. Remove multiplication from the loop and you get a hand-made `memcpy`.

Comment: Just don't do the multiplication in the for loop!

Comment: `std::copy_n(buffer, numSamples, mData);` for the raw copy or `std::transform(buffer, buffer + numSamples, mData, [](auto value) { return value * 1.0f / 32768; });` for the transformation would be clearer i.m.o.

Comment: *So, is there a way to transform the memcpy into a for* -- Why do you want to turn a very fast operation into one that isn't as fast?

Comment: The `memcpy` doesn't perform the `1.0f / 32768` calculation.  The `memcpy` function copies bytes; no other functionality is performed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the difference between these two?

```
for (int i = 0; i < numSamples; i++) {
  mData[sampleIndex++] = *buffer++ * (1.0f / 32768);
}
// and
memcpy(&mData[sampleIndex], buffer, (numSamples * sizeof(float)));
```

These are quite different given the `* (1.0f / 32768);`.  I assume the code compare is setting the scaling difference aside. [@Thomas Matthews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65945183/how-to-transform-this-memcpy-into-a-for/65946068#comment116597719_65945183).

- Important: `buffer, sampleIndex` has different values after the `for` loop.
- `*buffer++` needs no code change should the type of `buffer` change. `* sizeof(float)` obilgies a code change.  Could have used `* sizeof *buffer`.
- `mempcy()` is optimized code per that platform.  `for()` loops can only do so much.  In particular, `mempcy()` assumes `mData, buffer` do not overlap.  The `for()` loop may not be able to make that optimization.
- This `for` uses `int` indexing where `memcpy()` uses `size_t`.  Makes a difference with huge arrays.
- `memcpy()` tolerates an unaligned pointers. `mData[sampleIndex++] = *buffer++ ..` does not.

"the first copies numSamples float values to mData, one by one. " is a not certain.  A smart compiler may be able to make certain parallel copies depending on the context and act *as if* copying was done *one by one*.

Post the entire block of code/function that uses these 2 approaches for a better compare.

Answer (score 1):

I gather from your post that you want to make a `memcpy` similar copy but using a `for` loop, that being the case you just need do use the same `for` loop but without the multiplication part:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numSamples; i++){
    mData[sampleIndex++] = *buffer++;
}
```

Note that `memcpy` can be more effective than a `for` loop given the conditions ([see Maxim Egorushkin and  Jeremy Friesner comments bellow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65945183/how-to-transform-this-memcpy-into-a-for/65945272?noredirect=1#comment116596919_65945272)) so you may want to keep it that way.

Another, more idiomatic, and, I would argue, better way to implement the  operations you are performing is to use the C++ library provided methods as sugested by [Ted Lyngmo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65945183/how-to-transform-this-memcpy-into-a-for/65945272?noredirect=1#comment116596567_65945183) and [rustyx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65945183/how-to-transform-this-memcpy-into-a-for/65945272?noredirect=1#comment116597338_65945272).

Disclaimer: As I was writing my answer, [Martin York posted a comment with a similar solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65945183/how-to-transform-this-memcpy-into-a-for/65945272#comment116596455_65945183), that being the case, credit to him as well.

Comment: `memcpy` may not be _far more efficient_. Unlike `memcpy`, the compiler may know alignment and size of the data involved and vectorize the loop into a more efficient SIMD-copy with no `memcpy` prologue and epilogue. Same applies to `memset`.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin, I added a "usually" following your comment.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin I get the impression that modern C++ compilers are often clever enough to take their knowledge of alignment and data-size and use it to generate calls to different specialized flavors of `memcpy()` based on which would be most efficient and still work.

Comment: The conditions when `memcpy` is more efficient is when the size and alignment aren't known, and the size is under a specific limit. After that size, plain `rep movsb` beats [`memcpy`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43343231/enhanced-rep-movsb-for-memcpy) on modern hardware.

Comment: Sure, but does it beat `memcpy_aligned_using_sse()` (i.e. a hypothetical, less-general version of `memcpy()` that the compiler knows about and will call instead of the general-purpose `memcpy()` when conditions permit) ?

Comment: @JeremyFriesner You are right, modern compilers treat `memcpy` as _a copy is required, use the best method given all available information at the call site_. But they do so for loops as well.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin as a C guy I'm always compelled to use the 'mem's. The fact is that modern compilers are very capable when it comes to optimize less efficient code. Your discussion with Jeremy is a nice adition to the topic.

Comment: Fair enough. As a C++ guy I prefer assignment and initializer list to `memcpy`, and `whatever x = {};` to `memset` and expect the compiler to choose the best method for me. Those `size` arguments to `memcpy` and `memset` have been a source of bugs in 3rd-party code till this very day. Not to mention that `memcpy` and `memset` do not stop compiling when elements accidentally become no longer trivially copyable.

Comment: @anastaciu C++ isn't C. `memcpy` isn't very idiomatic C++, as it's not type-safe. `std::copy_n` is. The end result (provided the absence of UB) will be identical (and if not, file a bug with Microsoft ;).

Comment: @rustyx Or file a bug against another compiler: https://lemire.me/blog/2020/01/20/filling-large-arrays-with-zeroes-quickly-in-c/

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin, yes, old habits die hard, still, I would not have suggested it in a C++ setting wiht no context behind it, but given the fact the OP is using it, I went with it. The use of the `std::copy` methods would probably be the best way to go.

Comment: I do not disagree strongly, but the reality is when there is a possibility for mistake, that possibility realises one day (function of the square root of occurence). `size` argument calculation for `memcpy` and `memset` is a source of bugs in my experience, and by not using `memcpy` or `memset` I eliminate this class of bugs in my code completely.

Comment: @rustyx, right you are. Still I would argue against Microsoft bug correction, what is a good Microsoft implementation without some UB? It would lose its charm :)

Answer (score 1):

> What is the difference between these two?

The former performs a calculation on the source array while copying the result into another array a float at a time.

The latter copies the content of the array byte at a time into another without calculation.

> So, is there a way to transform the memcpy into a for?

Yes. Here is a naïve way to transform it:

```
auto dest_c = static_cast<unsigned char*>(mData + sampleIndex);
auto src_c = static_cast<const unsigned char*>(buffer);
auto end = src_c + numSamples * sizeof(float);
for (; src_c < end;) { // or while(src_c < end)
    *dest_c++ = *src_c++;
}
```

The actual implementation of the standard function is likely more complex, involving optimisations related to copying long sequences.

---

Since you don't appear to need the generic reinterpretation aspect of `std::memcpy`, perhaps a simpler alternative would suffice:

```
auto dest = mData + sampleIndex;
auto src = buffer;
auto end = src + numSamples;
for (; src < end;) {
    *dest++ = *src++;
}
```

Or perhaps another standard algorithm:

```
std::copy(buffer, buffer + numSamples, mData + sampleIndex);
```

Comment: I agree that `while(c)` can be dropped from the next version of the standard, `for(;c;)` does it.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Same number of characters -> equally  optimal :) That said, I used an extra space.

Comment: Fair enough, I have no further arguments, your honour.